# Windows C++ child window unresponsive

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

Using mixed managed/unmanaged C++ (Visual Studio 2008) I'm opening a windows form child window from a DirectX application. Weird stuff indeed, but it works, mostly. If I use `showDialog()` the child window works perfectly, but obviously the main app stops running (until the child is closed). If I use `show()` life is good, but the child has subtle issues. A textbox works and accepts input for example, but you can no longer use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move to different controls. Mnemonics (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+hotkey) have stopped working as well.

I'm a huge keyboard shortcut fan, so this is very annoying. To make it worse, I'm not even sure how to Google this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To resolve the tabbing problem either use a separate thread to create the dialog and call showDialog(), or call IsDialogMessage in your main message loop. Assuming you control that.

Comment: using a separate thread works! have't tried IsDialogMessage() but froom the docs it sounds like it would probably work too. if you make this an answer, i'll accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the tabbing problem either use a separate thread to create the dialog and call showDialog(), or call IsDialogMessage in your main message loop.